# Combining Three Images into One Output Image Python

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, python

I have to combine three images that are inside one single image into one output image in Python. This has to be done using Gamma corrections, Histogram
equalization, filters convolutions (gradient, median, bilateral, sharpening…
etc), Fourier transform and manipulations in frequency domain.

I know it sounds confusing, but this is what I have to do:
Input image:

[image: Input image]

Output image:

[image: Output image]

I have tried cutting up the image and stacking with this code:

```
def clean_baby(im):
    # Segment the input image into three separate images
    height, width = im.shape
    third_width = width // 3
    im1 = im[:, :third_width]
    im2 = im[:, third_width:2*third_width]
    im3 = im[:, 2*third_width:]

    # Apply a perspective transformation to each imag

    # Combine the three corrected images into one
    return np.hstack((im1, im2, im3))
```

but it does not work, and I do not think this is the best idea.

If you know what a better method will be to do this, I would really appreciate the help since I do not know what to do here.

Comment: This looks and sounds like homework.  Is it?  Has the class gone over similar example?  It looks like you're being asked to take three source images, of which the one you show in the upper left of your first picture is not geometrically distorted.  The other two are distorted and rotated -- so presumably you need to find the best fit between each of those images and the "good" image, then do some sort of maximum-likelihood estimation of pixel brightness -- is that correct?